# How to Control Number of Parameters Entered to Function

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, shell, function

I am trying to make a simple menu-driven calculator script. I want there to be an error message displayed whenever the user does not enter the correct parameters when they call the add() or subtract() functions. Such as more than 3 parameters (the operator is included), no parameters ( equals 0) and wrong operator ( not subtract or minus)

I know that # means parameter entered to the command line so that part is wrong, but am not sure how to make it check for parameters entered into function

```
#!/bin/bash  
display() {
echo "Calculator Menu" 
echo "Please select an option between add, subtract or exit"
echo "A. Add"
echo "B. Subtract"
echo "C. Exit"
} 
#initialize choice n
choice=n 

if [ $# > 3 ] 
then 
echo " You need to input 3 parameters. "
fi

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then 
echo " You have not entered any parameters, please input 3. "
fi 

if  [ $2 != "+" ] || [ $2 != "-" ]
then
echo " Please enter an add or subtract operator."
fi


add() {
echo " The sum of $one + $three equals $(( $one $op $three ))"
}

subtract () {
echo " The difference of $one - $three equals $(( $one $op $three )) "
} 

while [ $choice != 'C' ] 
do display
read choice
if [ $choice = 'A' ] 
then 
read -p "Please enter two operands and the operator '+': " one op three
add $one $op $three

elif [ $choice = 'B' ] 
then
read -p " Please enter two operands and the operator '-': " one op three
subtract $one $op $three

elif [ $choice = 'C' ]
then
echo "Thank you for using this program. The program will now exit." 
fi 

done
 


sleep 3

exit 0
```

Comment: Suggest you test $# = 3 before referencing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

`$#` is still what you want. It includes the number of positional parameters passed to a function, or on the command line to a script. See the Positional Parameters section of [Internal Variables](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).

For example, modifying your `add` function like this:

```
add() {
    if [ $# -ne 3 ]
    then
            echo " ERROR: Incorrect number of arguments"
            return 1
    fi
    echo " The sum of $one + $three equals $(( $one $op $three ))"
}
```

would return an error for `2+2` (one argument) but would return the calculation from `2 + 2` (three arguments).

Possibly you are asking how to *call* the 3 tests from the `add` and `subtract` functions and include the arguments. In that case, I would wrap those tests in another function:

```
test_args() {
    if [ $# > 3 ]
    ...12 lines omitted...
    fi
}
```

Use `$@` to pass all the same arguments on to the `test_args` function. For example:

```
add() {
    test_args $@
    echo " The sum of $one + $three equals $(( $one $op $three ))"
}
```

Comment: Note that if you pass a single argument, such as `2+2`, you will get an error when attempting to evaluate the following:
```if  [ $2 != "+" ] || [ $2 != "-" ]```
But that is a separate issue.